# don't coming another array values only coming last value

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I develop app with java and firebase. I added user's userId in array after every register, but don't coming another userId only coming last register userId.

There is only last register user's userId in logcat. why didn't come another user's user id?

[image: logcat view]

```
      public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> userIdArray=new ArrayList<String>();
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);           
        FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String currentid=user.getUid();
        userIdArray.add(currentid);
        DocumentReference reference;
        FirebaseFirestore firestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        reference=firestore.collection("Users").document(currentid);

        reference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if(task.getResult().exists()){
                    DocumentSnapshot document= task.getResult();
                    String nameResult=task.getResult().getString("name");
                    String ageResult=task.getResult().getString("age");
                    String url=task.getResult().getString("profile_photo");
                    String eMail=task.getResult().getString("email");

                    List<String> hobbiesResult=(List<String>) document.get("Hobbies");

                    Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                        if (entry.getKey().equals("Hobbies")) {
                          Log.d("TAG", entry.getValue().toString());
                          hobbies.setText(entry.getValue().toString());

                        }
                    }
                    Picasso.get().load(url).into(imageView);
                    name.setText(nameResult);
                    mail.setText(eMail);
                    age.setText(ageResult);
                }
            }
        });
    }
   public String getRandomUserId() {
        Random random=new Random();
        int index = random.nextInt(userIdArray.size()+1);
        String randomUserId=userIdArray.get(index);
        return randomUserId;

    }
```

Comment: Because you always create a new List in the the `onCreate` method: `userIdArray=new ArrayList<String>();`. If you want your list to not reset with every call of that method, you need to initialize the list outside that method and not always create a new one

Comment: i removed method from onCreate but problem continue :( @OHGODSPIDERS

Comment: Because you make the same error in your getRandomUserId method. Just initialize the list once in its declaration `ArrayList<String> userIdArray = new ArrayList<>();` and don't do `userIdArray = new ArrayList<>();` anywhere else except if you ecplivitly want to delete your list and create a completly new one

Comment: I removed it from there too, unfortunately it continued

Comment: i edited my code. you can see new version @OHGODSPIDERS